# In HTML5 want to validate password and confirm password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate password and confirm password in HTML5.  By using function required  I have validated for empty value. But not able to validate password and confirm password

**HTML:**

```
<form id="registration" name="registration" action="registrationaction.php" method="POST">
<input type="password" class="agent-input registerinput" name="pswd" id="pswd">
<input type="password" class="agent-input registerinput " name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
$().ready(function() 
{
    $("#registration").validate({
            rules:  pswd: {
                    required: true
                },
                            confirmpassword: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            messages
                pswd: "Please enter password",
                            confirmpassword: "Please enter valid confirm password",                   
            },      
            submitHandler: function() { $('#registration').submit(); }
        });
    });
```

Comment: write logic for that in jquery...

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function() { // code here })` you didn't write `document` keyword.

Comment: yeah you can check the equality of both by fetching the values in some variable through jquery.

Comment: please also be aware that this validation in effect means nothing, other than as a convenience factor for the user, since it is client side. also include this check from the server side as well.

Comment: did you see the code of @user2727841...

Comment: @user2727841 - But you have not mentioned how to check the code?

Comment: run this file at your browser!!! and check the code if it is working thats fine if not check why???

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary - can you please tell me the logic in jquery?

Comment: @Jazz get both passwords values in jquery & make comparision then check their equality............

Comment: @AndrewBrown: "Confirm password" is perfectly safe to check only client-side as long as the site requires JavaScript anyway. It's only to prevent the user from making a typo in his password anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods to confirm the two password match. However, assuming you want to utilize the jQuery Validation Plugin (which your question seems to use), changing your Javascript code to this will do the job:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#registration").validate({
        rules: { 
            pswd: {
                required: true
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#pswd"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pswd: "Please enter password",
            confirmpassword: "Please enter valid confirm password"
        },      
        submitHandler: function() { $('#registration').submit(); }
    });
});
```

I should point out that your Javascript example had several issues (unclosed brackets, etc). They've been corrected in the example above.

And for more amazingness you can create with jQuery Validation Plugin, definitely remember to see [their documentation webpage](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) for an easy-to-read list of available options.

P.S.
To everyone insisting that $().ready() must be changed, I'd like to point out that it is perfectly valid syntax according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (although not recommended, it is valid).

Comment: I must reaffirm what Andrew Brown stated in an earlier comment. It is highly recommended to have a server-side check as well. If a visitor's web browser does not have Javascript enabled, this entire block of validation code will not run at all. Implementing a Javascript check is convenient and perfect for the average visitors, but it's important to have those server-side checks as well for those edge cases. I suggest researching "server-side form validation tutorial" to get some ideas on how it's done.

Comment: Also, glad to hear it helped! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code within proper ready() function. I think the code you have provided must be throwing errors. Anyhow two correct ways to do this would be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code comes here
});


$(function() {
    //your code comes here
});
```

Inside these you can write the form validation code. Please be clear on the point that **you can only do this with JavaScript**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registration").validate({
            rules:  pswd: {
                    required: true
                },
                            confirmpassword: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            messages
                pswd: "Please enter password",
                            confirmpassword: "Please enter valid confirm password",                   
            },      
            submitHandler: function() { $('#registration').submit(); }
        });
    });
```

**OR**

```
$(function() {
   $("#registration").validate({
            rules:  pswd: {
                    required: true
                },
                            confirmpassword: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            messages
                pswd: "Please enter password",
                            confirmpassword: "Please enter valid confirm password",                   
            },      
            submitHandler: function() { $('#registration').submit(); }
        });
});
```

both function `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });` and `$(function() { // code here });` are equivalent. **Don't forget to code for server side validation**!!!